# How to improve the performance of Caffe with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, caffe

I am following this tutorial [Face detection with OpenCV and deep learning](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) to create and face detection software using OpenCV3, Caffe and Python3. 
This is the used code:

```
    # USAGE
    # python detect_faces.py --image rooster.jpg --prototxt deploy.prototxt.txt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel

# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
                help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
                help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.40,
                help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
# by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
print(h)
dimension_x =h
dimension_y=h
print(image.shape[:2])
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (dimension_x, dimension_y)), 1.0, (dimension_x, dimension_y), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
# predictions
print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

print(detections)

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for the
        # object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        print(confidence, startX, startY, endX, endY )
        print(box)
        # draw the bounding box of the face along with the associated
        # probability
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

print(type(image))
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

When I run the the code from the command line using this command:

```
python detect_faces.py  --prototxt  deploy.prototxt.txt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel --confidence=0.45 --image 14.jpg
```

I get this result [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3JaY.jpg):[image: image with detected faces, each face has a box with a score]
* [Source](http://paulaspreschoolandkindergarten.blogspot.nl/2014/05/)*

The result is quite good, but we notice at the most lower-left location on the picture where I drew a blue circle that the program has detected the face of the girl twice. The first detection is good, but the second one isn't! 
I have searched online for a method to give the model/program feedback so that it will learn that the detected object (surrounded by blue circle and has 51.11% accuracy isn't a face. So it can avoid giving it back as face!

So my question is, how can I finetune the used Caffe model to exclude non-face objects which are detected as faces for the future face detection tasks?

My question is not only about this specific situation, but in general for all object which are detected as faces while they are not. The used image is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

@Peshmerge, For a specific image you can vary input blob dimensions to achieve the best results.
In example, `900x900`:

```
python object_detection.py --model opencv_face_detector.caffemodel --config opencv_face_detector.prototxt --mean 104 177 123  --thr 0.4 --input P1280471.JPG --width 900 --height 900
```

[image]

a script: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer! I will try it, but I need first to update opencv to 3.4.1. Running the code you mentioned requires some functions which aren't available in 3.4.0! 
But separately from editing the parameter, how can I give feedback back to the model? Do I have retrain the whole model?

Comment: Actually, it's just a script. You may achieve similar output by replacing `(dimension_x, dimension_y)` to `(900, 900)`. Please add also two `False` arguments at `blobFromImage` to indicate that you need BGR input image but not RGB and to disable cropping (see https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga152367f253c81b53fe6862b299f5c5cd). What do you mean by _give feedback back to the model_? Do you mean how to choose right `width` and `height` of input?

Comment: I have indeed edited my code with the parameters you already gave, but unfortunately it didn't give me the same result you got (your image). And to be honest py playing with the parameters and especially with the height and width, I could get a good result. For example in the original code of the tutorial, he uses 300*300 which doesn't give good results.
I will post my answer about 'giving feedback' in a new comment.

Comment: By giving feedback back to the algorithm I meant: editing or finetuning the program so that it will just know that the detected object (in my original image) isn't a face, so that it can avoid repeating the mistake. I think that is the whole point of DNN, that it can learn and adapt. 
Sorry if I can't explain it very well. I hope my point is clear!

Comment: Peshmerge, I think I see what you mean. For a particular image we always can choose pre-processing procedures which give the best prediction. However we need to measure an accuracy of a model over sets of images (test datasets). In example, by resizing to 300x300 we can achieve better metrics than by using any size inputs (see details at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn#face-detection).

Comment: The second problem is more complicated. Usually, networks are trained for specific problems and it could be possible that train dataset had no enough horizontally oriented faces or more adult people rather the children. You're right that one of the common ways to improve performance of trainable algorithms is to add more data for "hard cases". Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't train deep learning networks but you can use an [origin framework](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) with your data.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answers Dmitry! My latest question
So you mean I can improve the performance by retraining the Caffe model separately and this has nothing to do with Opencv. Right?

Comment: We need to have some numeric accuracy metrics. Try to choose a representative dataset and measure an accuracy on it. I'd like to recommend you COCO object detection evaluation tool. [OpenCV uses](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/misc/face_detector_accuracy.py) it to compare this neural network and cascades.

Comment: I have sent you an email! Would you please take a look? 
My email address is p[dot]morad[at]hotmail.com