# How to improve the performance of face detection model base on Caffe in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, caffe

I'm following this tutorial (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/#post_downloads) to create a face detection program using "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel". 
Also, I found another post ([How to improve the performance of Caffe with OpenCV in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633399/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-caffe-with-opencv-in-python)). From this post I found that I could resize the input image with different size to have better accuracy on face detection. For instance, resize to 900 by 900 rather than 300 by 300 to have better result on detecting multiple faces in one single image.

But there is a problem, the input size of the model is 300 by 300, why we could just resize the input image with different resolution?
In the concept of human vision, resize to a square image would squeeze our face horizontally or vertically, is it just like some concepts of "after resizing the feature of our faces won't change a lot"?

Here is the code below:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True, help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.50, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
# by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
print(h)
dimension_x =h
dimension_y=h
print(image.shape[:2])
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (dimension_x, dimension_y)), 1.0, (dimension_x, dimension_y), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
# pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
# predictions
print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

print(detections)

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for the
        # object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        # draw the bounding box of the face along with the associated
        # probability
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

print(type(image))
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```